# Possible to use placeholders in sys_properties?

Tags: javascript, servicenow

Is it possible to create a sys_property value such as:

```
This incident has been picked up by {person_name} for further investigation
```

And then in the code use something like:

```
var assignee = "John Doe";
var prop = gs.getProperty('my_property_name');    
// and now replace person_name with the value of assignee variable?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`RecordToHTML`](https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/paris/server_legacy/c_RecordToHTMLAPI) API, traditionally it's used for using the fields from a record as the replacement values for the string fields, however, with the help of [`.setValue()`](https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/paris/server_legacy/c_RecordToHTMLAPI#r_RTH-setValue_S_S), you can bypass the record arguments and specify your own values. Note for this to work your "variables" in your string need to be wrapped in `${}` and not `{}`:

```js
var prop = gs.getProperty('my_property_name'); // "This incident has been picked up by ${person_name} for further investigation";
var assignee = "John Doe";
 
var rth = new RecordToHTML(null, null, prop);
rth.setValue("person_name", assignee); // replaces ${person_name} with "John Doe"

var result = rth.toString(); // "This incident has been picked up by John Doe for further investigation"
```

The above is a little hacky, as it bypasses the record arguments. If you want to go for another appraoch you can create your own function for this. You can firstly put `assignee` into an object that holds the key `person_name` and points to your `assignee` value, then use a function to replace values within `{<key>}` using the `key` as the key to index your object:

```
function interpolate(str, obj) {
  return str.replace(/{([^}]+)}/g, function(match, key) {
    return obj[key] || match; // if we can't find the key, return the original `{key}`
  });
}

var variableMap = {
  "person_name": "John Doe" // assignee
};

var prop = gs.getProperty('my_property_name');
var msg = interpolate(prop, variableMap); // "This incident has been picked up by John Doe for further investigation"
```

---

There are some other options that you can use that may do what you're after that are also worth looking into. One being using the first arguments of [`RecordToHTML()`](https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/newyork/server_legacy/c_RecordToHTMLAPI) and another being [`gs.getMessage()`](https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/paris/server/no-namespace/c_GlideSystemScopedAPI#r_ScopedGlideSystemGetMessage_String_Object). RecordToHTML can also be good if you have a particular record that contains the fields you want to replace from your string (note that your fields need to be wrapped in `${}`):

```
var rth = new RecordToHTML("incident", incidentSysId, "This incident has been picked up by ${assigned_to} for further investigation", false);
var result = rth.toString();
```

There is also `gs.getMessage()`, which comes *close*, but it doesn't allow for named "variables" within your string and requires you to use indexes. It also performs a table query / lookup in the `sys_ui_message` table each time it is called which may be overkill:

```js
// prop = This incident has been picked up by {0} for further investigation
var msg = gs.getMessage(prop, [assignee]);
```

Comment: Beautiful. I had been using `getMessage()` to achieve this but was wondering if `getProperty()` could do something too. This workaround sounds good enough for now.

Comment: @asprin no worries,  there is another option which uses `RecordToHTML()` which you can bypass the record arguments of and then use `setValue()` on the specify the string values